# Proper way of storing HTML in MySQL database and returning it via json?

Tags: php, html, json, api

I am looking to store HTML in a MySQL database, this will be added via a WYSIWYG editor on a webpage and posted via php to a MySQL database. This HTML is used to display news articles on a website. So what is the correct way of storing and returning this, I don't want to remove HTML so I guess it's a straight insert via pdo bind parameters and then just select and display on the webpage when returning? Or should I be using any functions to encode/ make safe the HTML code.

Also as part of this I also need to return the news articles for a mobile app in a JSON api, I will use json_encode function on the returned data but should I be running any make safe functions on that too?

Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: The issue are: how to best store html from post, how to best retrieve from db and echo onto site, and what the proper way to return HTML in json

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Save html into database directly as text received as post data

```
$htmlcontents = $_POST['htmlcontents'];
```

insert into db

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO dbname (htmlcontents) values('.$htmlcontents.')';
```

run the insert query

getting the stored html contents

```
$query = 'SELECT htmlcontents from dbname';
```

save the htmlcontents from database into a variable $htmlcontents.

sent the html as json to the client
    print json_encode(array('htmlcontents' => $htmlcontents));

use this json and append the htmlcontents to body

```
$(body).append(response.htmlcontents);
```

Comment: Thanks, although I believe that when inserting there should be some escaping due to sql injection?